# Client Dissconnect or down

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, network-programming

I have 2 Application in a visual studio Windows Forms App(.Net Framework 4) The names of my two programs are:

```
IpServer

IpClient
```

My problem is that I do not know what to do that when the IpClient Application closes or stops or the IpServer Application shows a message in messagebox.show("Client Is dissconnect")

IpServer Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace IpServer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        TcpListener tcplist;
        Socket s;
        private void init()
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            tcplist = new TcpListener(ip,5050);
            tcplist.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                s = tcplist.AcceptSocket();
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(replay));
                t.IsBackground = true;
                t.Start();
            }
        }
        private void replay()
        {
            Socket sc = s;
            NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(sc);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ns);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ns);
            string str = "";
            string response = "";
            try { str = reader.ReadLine(); }
            catch { str = "error"; }
            if (str == "register")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ok");
            }
            response = "registeredSucss,";
            writer.WriteLine(response);
            writer.Flush();
            ns.Close();
            sc.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(init));
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
            MessageBox.Show("Server run!!");
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
```

and IpClient Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace IpClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        TcpClient tcp;
        NetworkStream ns;
        StreamReader reader;
        StreamWriter writer;
        string str = "";

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                tcp = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1",5050);
                tcp.ReceiveBufferSize = 25000;
                tcp.NoDelay = true;
                ns = tcp.GetStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(ns);
                writer = new StreamWriter(ns);
                writer.WriteLine("register");
                writer.Flush();
                str = reader.ReadLine();
                string[] strsplit = null;
                strsplit = str.Split(',');
                if (strsplit[0] != "registeredSucss")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not connected");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your connected");
                }
                
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: When a client disconnects or otherwise disappears, the server should close the connection, release all resources allocated or created for the client connection, and and in a way forget that it ever existed. The server then continues to handle other clients and new connections.

Comment: Yes you are right now how do I do this in the above project code and do my codes have a structure problem? If possible, please correct the above project codes.

Comment: There are lots of examples online on how to setup a TCP client and server in c#. I would follow one of those templates/examples. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, and there is a lot of mess to what you did.

Comment: I just want to know how I can get a message from the server software when the client software is closed for any reason stating that the software is closed.

Comment: Or it is better to say how to find out if the client is connected to the server or not. (Client status in server session)

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: You cannot find out for sure if a client is still there without sending a message. Tcp is a disconnected protocol, each end can stay connected for 100 years and never send or receive a packet. Your server needs to ask the client if it is there every interval.

Comment: Can you help with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a complete example for you.

You can modify it according to your needs.

Simply connecting the client to the server without sending or receiving messages will not disconnect.

In the server and the client, there is a thread that continuously calls the receive function, and sends a message when the connection is disconnected.

```cs
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 2];
                    int length = socket.Receive(buffer);
                    if (length == 0) {
                    ///Write the desired operation
                    }
```

"Disconnect when closing the window" uses the formclosing event:

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        }
```

This is the control diagram used by the two windows:

IpClient：

[image]

IpServe:

[image]

This is the code for the two windows:

IpClient：

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IpClient {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Socket socket;//The socket responsible for the connection
        private void ConnectB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //Determine whether to request a connection repeatedly
            try {
                Log("Connected " + socket.LocalEndPoint.ToString() + "\nPlease do not request the connection repeatedly");
            } catch {
                //Determine whether the input is wrong
                try {
                    socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    //Create IP address and port number;
                    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(Ipbox.Text);
                    int port = Convert.ToInt32(PortBox.Text);
                    IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
                    //Determine whether you can connect to the server
                    try {
                        socket.Connect(iPEndPoint);
                        Log("Connected " + socket.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
                        //Start receiving data thread
                        Thread th = new Thread(receive);
                        th.IsBackground = true;
                        th.Start();
                    } catch {
                        Log("Port is not open");
                    }                  
                } catch  {
                    socket = null;
                    Log("Input error");
                }
            }
        }

        private void Log(string str) {
            ClientLog.AppendText(str + "\r\n");
        }
        private void receive() {
            while (true) {
                //Determine whether the data can be received
                try {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 2];
                    int length = socket.Receive(buffer);
                    if (length == 0) {
                        Log("Port is not open");
                        CloseSocket(socket);
                        socket = null;
                        break;
                    }
                    string txt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
                    Log(socket.RemoteEndPoint + ":\r\t" + txt);
                } catch {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        }

        private void CloseB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (socket != null) {
                CloseSocket(socket);
                socket = null;
                Log("Connection closed");
                
            } else {
                Log("Not connected");
            }
        }

        private void SendB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                string txt = SendText.Text;
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txt);//ascii encoding
                socket.Send(buffer);
            } catch {
                Log("Not connected");
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
            if (socket != null) {
                CloseSocket(socket);
                socket = null;
            }
        }

        //Disconnect socket
        private void CloseSocket(Socket o) {
            try {
                o.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                o.Disconnect(false);
                o.Close();
            } catch {
                Log("error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IpServer：

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IpServer {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Socket socketSend;//Socket responsible for communication
        Socket socketListener;//Socket responsible for monitoring
        Dictionary<string, Socket> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Socket>();//Store the connected Socket
        private void listnerB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //Create a listening socket
            //SocketType.Stream streaming corresponds to the tcp protocol
            //Dgram, datagram corresponds to UDP protocol
            socketListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try {
                //Create IP address and port number;
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(Ipbox.Text);
                int port = Convert.ToInt32(PortBox.Text);
                IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
                //Let the listening socket bind the ip and port number
                socketListener.Bind(iPEndPoint);
                Log("Listen successfully" + ip + "\t" + port);
                //Set up the listening queue
                socketListener.Listen(10);//Maximum number of connections at a time
                Thread thread = new Thread(Listen);
                thread.IsBackground = true;
                thread.Start(socketListener);
        } catch  {
                Log("Failed to listen");
    }
}

        //Use threads to receive data
        private void Listen(object o) {
            Socket socket = o as Socket;
            while (true) {
                //The socket responsible for monitoring is used to receive client connections
                try {
                    //Create a socket responsible for communication
                    socketSend = socket.Accept();
                    dictionary.Add(socketSend.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), socketSend);
                    clientCombo.Items.Add(socketSend.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                    clientCombo.SelectedIndex = clientCombo.Items.IndexOf(socketSend.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                    Log("Connected " + socketSend.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                    //Start a new thread to receive information from the client
                    Thread th = new Thread(receive);
                    th.IsBackground = true;
                    th.Start(socketSend);
                } catch  {
                    continue;
                }        
            }           
        }

        //The server receives the message from the client
        private void receive(object o) {
            Socket socketSend = o as Socket;
            while (true) {
                //Try to connect to the client
                try {
                    //After the client connects successfully, the server receives the message from the client
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 2];//2M大小
                     //Number of valid bytes received
                    int length = socketSend.Receive(buffer);
                    if (length == 0) {
                        string tmpIp = socketSend.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                        Log(tmpIp + " Offline");
                        clientCombo.Items.Remove(tmpIp);
                        //Try to delete the connection information
                        try {
                            clientCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        } catch  {
                            clientCombo.Text = null;
                        }
                        CloseSocket(dictionary[tmpIp]);
                        dictionary.Remove(tmpIp);                        
                        break;
                    }
                    string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
                    Log(socketSend.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "\n\t" + str);
                } catch {           
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Log(string str) {
            ServerLog.AppendText(str + "\r\n");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //Cancel errors caused by cross-thread calls
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        }

        //Send a message
        private void SendB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            string txt = SendText.Text;
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txt);
            try {
                string ip = clientCombo.SelectedItem.ToString();//Get the selected ip address
                Socket socketsend = dictionary[ip];
                socketsend.Send(buffer);
            } catch{
                Log("Transmission failed");
            }
        }

        private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                try {
                    string tmpip = socketSend.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();                    
                    CloseSocket(dictionary[tmpip]);
                    dictionary.Remove(tmpip);
                    clientCombo.Items.Remove(tmpip);
                    try {
                        clientCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    } catch {
                        clientCombo.Text = null;
                    }
                    socketSend.Close();
                    Log(socketSend.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "Offline");
                    socketListener.Close();
                    Log("Listener is closed");
                } catch{
                    socketListener.Close();
                    Log("Listener is closed");
                }                            
            } catch {
                Log("close error");
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
            try {
                try {
                    string tmpip = socketSend.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                    CloseSocket(dictionary[tmpip]);
                    dictionary.Remove(tmpip);
                    clientCombo.Items.Remove(tmpip);
                    try {
                        clientCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    } catch {
                        clientCombo.Text = null;
                    }
                    socketSend.Close();
                    socketListener.Close();
                } catch {
                    socketListener.Close();
                }
            } catch {
            }
        }

        private void CloseSocket(Socket o) {
            try {
                o.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                o.Disconnect(false);
                o.Close();
            } catch  {
                Log(o.ToString() + "error");
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

**OutPut:**

Closing the window causes disconnection:

[image]

[image]

Disconnect manually:

[image]

Transfer data:

[image]

**If you have any question about my code, please add a comment below.**

Comment: Excellent Your answer was very good. Thank you very much.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for your very diligent answer. Wondering if you can update it to demonstrate use of secure connections?