# How do I fix "Operation not allowed on unconnected sockets"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, networking, network-programming, desktop-application

For a school project, I have to create a simple desktop chat app. I've gone for a client-server approach. After doing some research on TCP listeners and clients and following a few tutorials I produced the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace NetworkTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TcpClient client;
        public StreamReader STR;
        public StreamWriter STW;
        public string recieve;
        public string TextToSend;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IPAddress[] localIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

            foreach(IPAddress address in localIP)
            {
                if(address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    IPBox1.Text = address.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

       

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(PortBox1.Text));
            listener.Start();
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            STW.AutoFlush = true;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }

        private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new TcpClient();
            IPEndPoint IpEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IPBox2.Text), int.Parse(PortBox2.Text));

            try
            {
                ChatScreenBox.AppendText("Connect to Server" + "\n");
                STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                STW.AutoFlush = true;
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (client.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    recieve = STR.ReadLine();
                    this.ChatScreenBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
                    {
                        ChatScreenBox.AppendText("You: " + recieve + "\n");
                    }));
                recieve = "";
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                STW.WriteLine(TextToSend);
                this.ChatScreenBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    ChatScreenBox.AppendText("Me: " + TextToSend + "\n");
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sending Failed");
            }
            backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
        }

        private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(MessageTextBox.Text != "")
            {
                TextToSend = MessageTextBox.Text;
                backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            MessageTextBox.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

UI: https://ibb.co/jk2HRcJ

In theory it should work however as soon as I try to send a message I get the alert "Operation not allowed on unconnected sockets".

Why is this? And how can I resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance

```
                               .
```

Comment: You create a new TcpClient, but you don't actually connect it to anywhere, and the reader/writer here appear to be still the server ones...? Note: all of TcpClient, TcpListener, StreamReader and StreamWriter are pretty unhelpful and unnecessary - they don't really simplify much over just using Socket or maybe NetworkStream on top of Socket. But network code is *hard* - really really hard. Describing all the pitfalls of network code is not feasible in a Stack Overflow post

Comment: Is there any update in this issue? If you accept it, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you must create a connection before you can operate on it.

For socket, I once wrote a [detailed sample tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69493368/16764901), you can refer to it.

If you have any questions about this，please comment bellow and I'll check it out.